# Assigning string with boolean expression

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to understand this code from someone else's project. If you want the context it's here: https://github.com/newsapps/beeswithmachineguns/blob/master/beeswithmachineguns/bees.py#L501

`IS_PY2` is just a boolean variable, `True` if the Python major version is 2.
I know that a non-empty string is `True`, but for some reason I don't understand `openmode` is assigned either `'w'` or `'wt'` rather than `True` or `False`.

```
openmode = IS_PY2 and 'w' or 'wt'
openkwargs = IS_PY2 and {} or {'encoding': 'utf-8', 'newline': ''}
```

Could someone explain the result?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ternary boolean expression works as:

```
>>> 2 and 3 or 4
3
>>> 0 and 3 or 4
4
```

So, this expression:

```
openmode = IS_PY2 and 'w' or 'wt'
```

Become in Python 2:

```
openmode = True and 'w' or 'wt'
```

Which is equivalent to

```
openmode = 'w' or 'wt'
```

So, i gives `w`.

Under Python 3, IS_PY2 is False, giving:

```
openmode = False and 'w' or 'wt'
```

Which is equivalent to

```
openmode = False or 'wt'
```

Giving `wt`.

---

All of this is to specify explicitely that the openmode is for text files, not binary, which is indicated by `w` in Python2 and `wt` in Python3.

While the Python3 `t` mode is the default one, this is not necessary to precise it.

See [this answer about `wt` mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23051095/3077939).

---

Finally, i think that the following is much more readable:

```
openmode = 'w' if IS_PY2 else 'wt'
```

And this one, much more simple:

```
openmode = 'w'
```

Answer (score 11):

The `and` and `or` operators *don't* simply perform a boolean operation on their operands, giving a boolean result. The result they give is *always* one of their operands. These operators evaluate from left to right, with `and` having a higher precedence than `or`, and they short-circuit, meaning that they stop evaluating their operands as soon as possible.

In pure boolean logic, `False and x` is `False`, no matter what `x` is, so there's no need to examine `x`. The Python expression `False and x` will give a result of `False` and it will not attempt to evaluate `x`. Thus `False and some_function()` will *not* call `some_function()`.

Similarly, `True and x` in pure boolean logic will have the same truth value as `x`, i.e., if `x` is `True` then `True and x` is `True`, otherwise its `False`.

But the Python `and` operator can handle arbitrary operands.

In `a and b` if `a` is false-ish, then `b` won't be evaluated and the result will be `a`. If `a` is true-ish, then `b` *will* be evaluated and become the result.

Here's a short demo, using Python 2:

```
print False and 'boolean'
print 0 and 'integer'
print '' and 'string'
print [] and 'list'
print

print True and 'boolean'
print 7 and 'integer'
print 'a' and 'string'
print [42] and 'list'
print

print True and False
print True and 0
print True and ''
print True and []
print
```

**output**

```
False
0

[]

boolean
integer
string
list

False
0

[]
```

(Those blank lines between `0` and `[]` are where the empty string is getting printed).

Similar considerations apply to the `or` operator.

In pure boolean logic, `True or x` is `True`, no matter what `x` is so if the first part of an `or` expression is True-ish we don't need to evaluate the second part. And `False or x` has the truth value of `x`.

```
print False or 'boolean'
print 0 or 'integer'
print '' or 'string'
print [] or 'list'
print

print True or 'boolean'
print 7 or 'integer'
print 'a' or 'string'
print [42] or 'list'
print

print False or False
print False or 0
print False or ''
print False or []
print
```

**output**

```
boolean
integer
string
list

True
7
a
[42]

False
0

[]
```

As I said earlier, these operators are evaluated left to right, and we can chain them if we want. Here are the "classic" cases:

```
print True and 'yes' or 'no'
print False and 'yes' or 'no'
```

Those statements are equivalent to

```
print (True and 'yes') or 'no'
print (False and 'yes') or 'no'
```

**output**

```
yes
no
```

That construction was common in early versions of Python. These days, it's far more common to see an *`if` expression*:

```
print 'yes' if True else 'no'
print 'yes' if False else 'no'
```

Which is generally considered to be more readable than the ternary expression using `and` and `or`. Also, `a and b or c` is *not* equivalent to `b if a else c` if `b` is false-ish.

However, it's still important to understand how this ternary `and ... or` thing works, especially if you need to read or maintain older code. And some old Pythonistas still prefer the `and ... or` form, as it's slightly shorter even if it is a little bewildering when you don't understand how it works. :)