# Python - breaking and grouping user input

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, user-input, nose

I'm doing an exercise I came over in Learn Python the Hard Way(ex 48). The aim is to group user input by referring to our lexicon. I'm using nose to test my script but I get multiple errors. I get 5 failures out of 6 when I run nosetests. I don't understand why I'm getting these errors though. Any help?

## errors

```
FAIL: tests.ex48_tests.test_verbs
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\nose\case.py", line 198, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "C:\Python\projects\skeleton2\tests\ex48_tests.py", line 13, in test_verbs
    assert_equal(scan("go").result, [('verb', 'go')])
AssertionError: <bound method scan.result of <ex48.lexicon.scan object at 0x03A8F3F0>> != [('verb', 'go')]

======================================================================
FAIL: tests.ex48_tests.test_stops
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\nose\case.py", line 198, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "C:\Python\projects\skeleton2\tests\ex48_tests.py", line 21, in test_stops
    assert_equal(scan("the").result(), [('stop', 'the')])
AssertionError: Lists differ: [('stop', 'the'), ('error', 'the')] != [('stop', 'the')]

First list contains 1 additional elements.
First extra element 1:
('error', 'the')

- [('stop', 'the'), ('error', 'the')]
+ [('stop', 'the')]

======================================================================
FAIL: tests.ex48_tests.test_noun
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\nose\case.py", line 198, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "C:\Python\projects\skeleton2\tests\ex48_tests.py", line 29, in test_noun
    assert_equal(scan("bear").result(), [('noun', 'bear')])
AssertionError: Lists differ: [('noun', 'bear'), ('error', 'bear')] != [('noun', 'bear')]

First list contains 1 additional elements.
First extra element 1:
('error', 'bear')

- [('noun', 'bear'), ('error', 'bear')]
+ [('noun', 'bear')]

======================================================================
FAIL: tests.ex48_tests.test_numbers
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\nose\case.py", line 198, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "C:\Python\projects\skeleton2\tests\ex48_tests.py", line 35, in test_numbers
    assert_equal(scan("1234").result(), [('number', 1234)])
AssertionError: Lists differ: [('error', '1234')] != [('number', 1234)]

First differing element 0:
('error', '1234')
('number', 1234)

- [('error', '1234')]
?     ---    -    -

+ [('number', 1234)]
?    ++++


======================================================================
FAIL: tests.ex48_tests.test_errors
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\nose\case.py", line 198, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "C:\Python\projects\skeleton2\tests\ex48_tests.py", line 45, in test_errors
    ('noun', 'princess')])
AssertionError: Lists differ: [('no[20 chars]r', 'bear'), ('error', 'IAS'), ('noun', 'princ[24 chars]ss')] != [('no[20 chars]r', 'IAS'), ('noun', 'princess')]

First differing element 1:
('error', 'bear')
('error', 'IAS')

First list contains 2 additional elements.
First extra element 3:
('noun', 'princess')

+ [('noun', 'bear'), ('error', 'IAS'), ('noun', 'princess')]
- [('noun', 'bear'),
-  ('error', 'bear'),
-  ('error', 'IAS'),
-  ('noun', 'princess'),
-  ('error', 'princess')]

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 6 tests in 0.027s

FAILED (failures=5)
```

**lexicon.py**

```
class scan(object):
    dirs = ['north','south','east','west','down','up','left','right','back']
    verbs = ['go','stop','kill','eat']
    stops = ['the','in','of','from','at','it']
    nouns = ['door','princess','bear','cabinet']
    numbers = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']

    def __init__(self, user_input):
        self.user_input = user_input

    def result(self):
        words = self.user_input.split()
        results = []

        for item in words:
            if item in scan.dirs:
                result = ('direction', item.lower())
                results.append(result)
            if item in scan.verbs:
                result = ('verb', item.lower())
                results.append(result)
            if item in scan.stops:
                result = ('stop', item.lower())
                results.append(result)
            if item in scan.nouns:
                result =('noun', item.lower())
                results.append(result)
            if item in scan.numbers:
                result = ('number', int(item))
                results.append(result)
            if item not in (scan.dirs or scan.verbs or scan.stops or
                            scan.nouns or scan.numbers):
                result = ('error', item)
                results.append(result)

        return results
```

**lexicon_test.py**

```
from nose.tools import *
from ex48.lexicon import scan


def test_direction():
    assert_equal(scan('north').result(), [('direction', 'north')])
    result = scan("north east south").result()
    assert_equal(result, [('direction', 'north'),
                          ('direction', 'east'),
                          ('direction', 'south')])

def test_verbs():
    assert_equal(scan("go").result, [('verb', 'go')])
    result = scan("go kill eat").result()
    assert_equal(result, [('verb', 'go'),
                          ('verb', 'eat')
                          ('verb', 'kill')])


def test_stops():
    assert_equal(scan("the").result(), [('stop', 'the')])
    result = scan("the in of").result()
    assert_equal(result, [('stop', 'the'),
                          ('stop', ' in'),
                          ('stop', 'of')])


def test_noun():
    assert_equal(scan("bear").result(), [('noun', 'bear')])
    result = scan("bear princess").result()
    assert_equal(result, [('noun', 'bear'),
                           ('noun', 'princess')])

def test_numbers():
    assert_equal(scan("1234").result(), [('number', 1234)])
    result = scan("3 91234").result()
    assert_equal(result, [('number', 3),
                          ('number', 91234)])

def test_errors():
    assert_equal(scan("ASDFADFASDF").result(), [('error', 'ASDFADFASDF')])
    result = scan("bear IAS princess").result()
    assert_equal(result, [('noun', 'bear'),
                          ('error', 'IAS'),
                           ('noun', 'princess')])
```

Comment: won't you want to `lower` word before you check `if item in scan.<some list>`?

Comment: Reduce the post to one failing question and include the error message. Always provide a **minimal** failing example, the effort alone will probably help you locate your error. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `if item not in (scan.dirs or scan.verbs or scan.stops or scan.nouns or scan.numbers):` doesn't do what you want it to do.

Comment: If you look at the test_error() you'll notice that IAS retains its case style. So I can't lower the word before the check mainly because of the error category.@depperm

Comment: >>> obj = scan("piGs can Fly")
>>> obj.result()
[('error', 'piGs'), ('error', 'can'), ('error', 'Fly')]

I get the right results when I run the code in my IDLE but now when I run with nosetests @PM2Ring

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, sorry I'm new here @Anthon

Comment: @Jephthah just follow Anthon's link on how to ask good questions. If you ask a good question, you will get a good answer :)

Comment: BTW, the SO Python community does _not_ recommend LPTHW. See [here](http://sopython.com/wiki/LPTHW_Complaints) for a few reasons why.

Comment: so what would you recommend @PM2Ring

Comment: There are some great tutorials mentioned in [What tutorial should I read?](http://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F)

Comment: @Jephthah Follow the link I provided and implement what it says, make your failing code minimal, so that it still generates **one** single error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of typos in your code and a couple of logic errors.

Here's a repaired version of your code, modified to run without the `nose` module (which I don't have).

```
class scan(object):
    dirs = ['north','south','east','west','down','up','left','right','back']
    verbs = ['go','stop','kill','eat']
    stops = ['the','in','of','from','at','it']
    nouns = ['door','princess','bear','cabinet']
    numbers = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']

    def __init__(self, user_input):
        self.user_input = user_input

    def result(self):
        words = self.user_input.split()
        results = []

        for item in words:
            if item in scan.dirs:
                result = ('direction', item.lower())
                results.append(result)
            elif item in scan.verbs:
                result = ('verb', item.lower())
                results.append(result)
            elif item in scan.stops:
                result = ('stop', item.lower())
                results.append(result)
            elif item in scan.nouns:
                result =('noun', item.lower())
                results.append(result)
            elif all(c in scan.numbers for c in item):
                result = ('number', int(item))
                results.append(result)
            else:
                result = ('error', item)
                results.append(result)

        return results

def assert_equal(u, v):
    print(u, v, u == v)

def test_direction():
    assert_equal(scan('north').result(), [('direction', 'north')])
    result = scan("north east south").result()
    assert_equal(result, [('direction', 'north'),
                          ('direction', 'east'),
                          ('direction', 'south')])

def test_verbs():
    assert_equal(scan("go").result(), [('verb', 'go')])
    result = scan("go kill eat").result()
    assert_equal(result, [('verb', 'go'),
                          ('verb', 'kill'),
                          ('verb', 'eat')])


def test_stops():
    assert_equal(scan("the").result(), [('stop', 'the')])
    result = scan("the in of").result()
    assert_equal(result, [('stop', 'the'),
                          ('stop', 'in'),
                          ('stop', 'of')])


def test_noun():
    assert_equal(scan("bear").result(), [('noun', 'bear')])
    result = scan("bear princess").result()
    assert_equal(result, [('noun', 'bear'),
                           ('noun', 'princess')])

def test_numbers():
    assert_equal(scan("1234").result(), [('number', 1234)])
    result = scan("3 91234").result()
    assert_equal(result, [('number', 3),
                          ('number', 91234)])

def test_errors():
    assert_equal(scan("ASDFADFASDF").result(), [('error', 'ASDFADFASDF')])
    result = scan("bear IAS princess").result()
    assert_equal(result, [('noun', 'bear'),
                          ('error', 'IAS'),
                           ('noun', 'princess')])

tests = (
    test_direction,
    test_verbs,
    test_stops,
    test_noun,
    test_numbers,
    test_errors,
)

for test in tests:
    print('\n' + test.__name__)
    test()
```

**output**

```
test_direction
[('direction', 'north')] [('direction', 'north')] True
[('direction', 'north'), ('direction', 'east'), ('direction', 'south')] [('direction', 'north'), ('direction', 'east'), ('direction', 'south')] True

test_verbs
[('verb', 'go')] [('verb', 'go')] True
[('verb', 'go'), ('verb', 'kill'), ('verb', 'eat')] [('verb', 'go'), ('verb', 'kill'), ('verb', 'eat')] True

test_stops
[('stop', 'the')] [('stop', 'the')] True
[('stop', 'the'), ('stop', 'in'), ('stop', 'of')] [('stop', 'the'), ('stop', 'in'), ('stop', 'of')] True

test_noun
[('noun', 'bear')] [('noun', 'bear')] True
[('noun', 'bear'), ('noun', 'princess')] [('noun', 'bear'), ('noun', 'princess')] True

test_numbers
[('number', 1234)] [('number', 1234)] True
[('number', 3), ('number', 91234)] [('number', 3), ('number', 91234)] True

test_errors
[('error', 'ASDFADFASDF')] [('error', 'ASDFADFASDF')] True
[('noun', 'bear'), ('error', 'IAS'), ('noun', 'princess')] [('noun', 'bear'), ('error', 'IAS'), ('noun', 'princess')] True
```

---

The first logic error I spotted was

```
if item not in (scan.dirs or scan.verbs or scan.stops 
    or scan.nouns or scan.numbers):
```

That *doesn't* test if `item` isn't in any of those lists. Instead, it first computes

```
scan.dirs or scan.verbs or scan.stops or scan.nouns or scan.numbers
```

using the standard rules for Python's `or` operator. `scan.dirs` is a non-empty list, so the result of that expression is simply `scan.dirs`.

So that `if` statement is equivalent to

```
if item not in scan.dirs:
```

which is clearly not what you intend to do.

For more info about how `or` and `and` work in Python, please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36551857/4014959) I wrote earlier this year.

We *could* implement that test using

```
if not any(item in seq for seq in (scan.dirs, scan.verbs, scan.stops, 
    scan.nouns, scan.numbers)):
```

but we don't need to do that. Instead we change most of those `if`s into `elif`s, and then anything that doesn't get successfully scanned must be an error, so we can handle that in the `else` block.

The second big logic error is your number test. You were trying to see if a multi-digit number string is a valid (positive) integer with

```
if item in scan.numbers:
```

but that test will only succeed if `item` is a single digit.

Instead we need to check that _all_digits of the number are, in fact, digits, and that's what

```
all(c in scan.numbers for c in item)
```

does.

However, there's a better way: we just use the `str` type's `.isdigit` method:

```
if item.isdigit():
```

I didn't use that in my code because I wanted to use your scan lists. Also, `.isdigit` can't handle negative numbers or decimal points, but you can easily add `'-'` and `'.'`  to `scan.numbers`.

Comment: Thanks a lot this definitely worked. I didn't realize how many typos I had made in that test script.

Comment: I actually never knew about the 'all' keyword, I prefer the isdigit() method as scan.numbers is meant to be within 0-9 only.

Comment: @Jephthah `all` and its "sister" function `any` are _very_ useful for general testing of multiple items. But when there are built-in specific tests that do what you want, like `isdigit` you should certainly use them instead.