# How is this conditional being handled?

Tags: python

I just ran into a weird bug in my code due to a typo where I had used a comma in a conditional rather than an `and` keyword. See the code below for a watered down example:

```
def foo():
    s = set([1, 2, 3])
    a = 4
    b = 5
    if (a, b in s):      # Should have been: if (a and b in s):
        print "Foo"

foo()  # prints "Foo"
```

Why does the conditional evaluate to `True`? Even if `a` is `None`, "Foo" gets printed.

Comment: I think you have created a tuple. It consists of `a` and the result of `b in s` and you are testing the truthiness of the tuple.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The expression `(a, b in s)` is a valid Python tuple. It will evaluate to Truth, regardless of its contents, as long as it has at least one element. (And this one has two).

Answer (score 3):

It's because `(a, b in s)` evaluates to the length-2 tuple `(4, False)`, and in python a tuple is considered to be `True` if it has nonzero length.

Answer (score 2):

The reason the code prints 'Foo' regardless of the value of a and wether b is in s is the the line:

`(a, b in s)`

is actually a tuple. The if statement checks if the tuple exists, and it does so Foo gets printed.
When

```
s=set([1,2,3])
a=None
b=5
```

the condition checked is

```
if(None, False):
```

Which is always true because

```
(None, False) #is a non empty tuple.
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, the expression `a, b in s` creates a tuple, and a non-empty tuple is truthy, i.e., it evaluates to `True` in a boolean context. Note that the commas create the tuple, not the parentheses, although parentheses are required in some contexts to avoid ambiguity, eg when passing a tuple literal as a single function argument.

BTW, parentheses are not required around the condition expression of an `if` statement in Python. They don't hurt, but the usual style convention is to omit them as unnecessary clutter.

Note that `if a and b in s:` does *not* test if both `a` and `b` are elements of the set `s`. To perform that test you should use the [`set.issuperset`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.issuperset) method:

```
if s.issuperset((a, b)):
```

Note that we need the extra parentheses here because we are passing the tuple `a, b` as a single argument.

That statement can also be written using the operator form of `.issuperset`:

```
if s >= set((a, b)):
```

but when using that form both operands must be sets (or frozensets), whereas the full method will accept any iterable as the *other* arg.

But getting back to your code... The expression

```
a and b in s
```

is equivalent to

```
a and (b in s)
```

If `a` is false-ish (i.e., `False`, 0, or an empty collection) the expression evaluates to `a` and the second part of the `and` expression is ignored. Otherwise (when `a` is truth-ish) the second part of the `and` expression is evaluated and that becomes the result.

In other words, if `a == 0` then `a and b in s` results in 0, but if `a` is any other number then `a and b in s` will result in `True` if `b` is in `s`, and it will result in `False` if `b` is not in `s`. Please see my answer to [Assigning string with boolean expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36551857/4014959) for further info (with numerous examples).