# weird behaviour in python conditional operators for "and" and "&"

Tags: python, python-2.7

Below are the different scenarios tried using '&' and 'and' conditional operators and its result. (using Python 2.7)

1. Using '&' operator:

[image]

2. Using 'and' operator:

[image]

Wondering why both conditional operators showing different behaviour?
Explanation with real scenarios would be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post *text* as text

Comment: Please see [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36550588/assigning-string-with-boolean-expression

Answer (score 5):

`&` **is not** a conditional operator. It stands for [the bitwise and](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators). Not only it is a different operator but also [the operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) is different (`and` is below `>` while `&` is above).

So first of all an example:

```
>>> 1 and 2
2
>>> 1 & 2
0
```

Now lets analyze your case:

```
>>> point = 1
>>> score = 2
>>> point == 1 & score > 0
```

Now the operator precedence kicks in and the last line is equivalent to

```
>>> point == (1 & score) > 0
```

Note that `==` and `>` have equivalent precedence. So lets evaluate that:

```
>>> 1 & score
0
>>> point == 0 > 0
```

The last line is equivalent to `(point == 0) > 0` (when operators have equal precedence then you simply go from left to right). Lets evaulate that:

```
>>> point == 0
False
>>> False > 0
False
```

All in all

```
>>> point == 1 & score > 0
False
```

Can you break down the evaluation for your second statement now?

Comment: Can you please elaborate the answer. 
if we do like (point == 1 & (score > 0)) => return true.

Comment: @PrashantkumarKB I've updated the answer. I'm not sure what you are trying to do but unless you are going to manipulate bits then don't use `&`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `&` is not actually a logical "and", it's a [bitwise operator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators). So it'll compare two numbers by each bit, and produce a number that has a bit set if both of the first two numbers had that bit set. So `1 & 2` will give you 0.

This wouldn't usually be a problem (True is 1, False is 0) - except that the [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) for & and `and` relative to `>` and `=` are different.

So `1 == 1 & 2 > 0` (the first case):

- This is interpreted as `1 == (1 & 2) > 0`, or `1 == 0 > 0`, and since `1 == 0` is False the whole thing is False.

Whereas `1 == 1 and 2 > 0` (the second case):

- This is interpreted as `(1 == 1) and (2 > 0)`, and since both of those cases are True, the whole thing is True.

Comment: You're absolutely right, and I've corrected my answer.

Answer (score 0):

and tests whether both expressions are logically True while & (when used with True/False values) tests if both are True.

Comment: >>> point = 1

>>> score = 2

>>> point == 1
True

>>> score > 0
True

Answer (score 0):

`&` is a [bitwise](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators) AND operator, whereas `and` is a logical operator.