# IF Statement Formatting Python

Tags: python, if-statement

I am trying to create a multiple layered IF statement and I am unsure if the statement below is correctly formatted.

I am having trouble reading the below nested IF statements, is it possible to write this code in a more efficient manner?

```
 if (a>= gT) and (cLow> rBT):
            print("Alpha 1")


            if (a_high> c_high) and (c_low < d_low):
                if (a> abc) and (a< c_low):
                    print("Final Count")

                    if (min(a, b) > min(c, d)) and \
                            (max(e,f) > max(g, h)): print("All Memory Deleted")
```

Comment: you can use something like the following to format your python code: https://codebeautify.org/python-formatter-beautifier

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's not a lot you can do to improve that, apart from making the indentation more uniform, removing redundant parentheses, combining the 2nd and 3rd `if` tests.

```
if a >= gT and cLow > rBT:
    print("Alpha 1")
    if a_high > c_high and c_low < d_low and a > abc and a < c_low:
        print("Final Count")
        if min(a, b) > min(c, d) and max(e,f) > max(g, h):
            print("All Memory Deleted")
```

The reason that it's safe to combine the 2nd and 3rd `if` tests is that the `and` operator "short-circuits", that is, in `expression_1 and expression_2` if `expression_1` is false then `expression_2` is *not* evaluated. For more info on this topic, with examples (in Python 2), please see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36551857/4014959).

---

BTW, it's best to avoid backslash continuation if you can: it's too fragile. Any space after the backslash breaks the continuation. Instead, you can often wrap a long expression in parentheses, if it doesn't already use some form of bracket. Eg,

```
if (min(a, b) > min(c, d) and 
    max(e,f) > max(g, h)):
```

See the Python style guide [PEP-0008](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length) for further details.

Answer (score 1):

While there may be a few reasons not to do this, execution time comes to mind, if readability of your nested if statements is that important to you, something like this works as well.

```
case_1 = case_2 = case_3 = False

try:
    case_1 = a >= gT and cLow > rBT
    case_2 = a_high > c_high and c_low < d_low and a > abc and a < c_low
    case_3 = min(a, b) > min(c, d) and max(e, f) > max(g, h)
except NameError:
   pass

if case_1:
    print("Alpha 1")
    if case_2:
        print("Final Count")
        if case_3:
            print("All Memory Deleted")
```

Comment: Sure, although you can get rid of many of those parentheses. One reason why pre-computing the conditions may not be appropriate is that some of the later computations may not be valid if the earlier conditions fail.

Comment: Yes, that is an important consideration.