# How does and&or work in print() function?

Tags: python

Saw this while searching and I couldn't understand the logic behind. How does and & or methods work in print()?

```py
T=[int(s) for s in input().split()]
print(T and sorted(sorted(T,reverse=True),key=abs)[0] or 0)
```

I've tried simplifying it to understand how it handles different inputs.

```py
print(A and B or C)
```

Returns B when B is not 0, and returns C when B is 0 but never gets to A.

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36551857/3717691): _"The `and` and `or` operators don't simply perform a boolean operation on their operands, giving a boolean result. The result they give is always one of their operands. These operators evaluate from left to right, with `and` having a higher precedence than `or`, and they short-circuit, meaning that they stop evaluating their operands as soon as possible."_

Comment: `print` always returns `None` and `A and B or C` works the same whether you print it or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an old style way to use ternary condition operator.

It has nothing related to `print`.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/394887/978434).

In most cases it does the same as this code

```
print(T and sorted(sorted(T,reverse=True),key=abs)[0] or 0)
print(sorted(sorted(T,reverse=True),key=abs)[0] if T else 0)
```

It works because of the way `and` and `or` works in Python - they do not return `bool`, but they return either first or second operand, depending if it casts to True or False.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47007761/978434) has more details.

Basically it's two operation

```
first = T and sorted(sorted(T,reverse=True),key=abs)[0]
```

`and` Return the first Falsy value if there are any, else return the last value in the expression.

So it either returns `[]` (possible Falsy value for T), or first element in sorted list.

```
result = first or 0
```

`or` Return the first Truthy value if there are any, else return the last value in the expression.

So if T is Truthy, we already have a Truthy value in `first` (unless it's 0, which is special case, but `0 or 0` is `0` anyway), it will be returned.

If `T` is `[]` - it will return 0.

Answer (score 0):

As part of the answer, if given a non-empty list, `T`, of integers, the expression

```
sorted(sorted(T,reverse=True),key=abs)[0]
```

returns the integer in the list which is closest to zero. For example, if `T = [3, -2, 4, 5]`, it will return `-2`.

The subtle point is what is does in a case like `T = [3, -2, 4, 2]` where `-2` and `2` are tied in being closest. In this case it will return `2` rather than `-2`. The logic for this particular case is that `sorted(T, reverse = True)` will put all of the positive numbers before any of the negative numbers, so that `2` will be before `-2`. When the result of that sort is then sorted again with `key = abs`, the `2` and `-2` are already in sorted order (relative to `key = abs`), so they *won't* be swapped, hence `2` rather than `-2` will be the first element of the list. The code is actually somewhat subtle and depends on the fact that [Timsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) is a stable sorting algorithm.