# I want to read url from text1 and write edit url to text2

Tags: python-3.x

```
def readfile(filename,mode="rt"):
    head = "<li><a href="""
    center =""" target="_blank">"""
    end ="<br></a></li>"
    with open(filename,mode) as fin:
        for line in fin:
        link = line
        length_link = len(link)
        twitter_name_after = link[twitter_name_before+5:]
        full_code = head+link+center+"@"+twitter_name_after+end
        writefile("C:/Users/Johny The Overlord/Documents/Code/test_1.txt",full_code)

def writefile(filename,contents,mode="wt"):
        with open(filename,mode) as fout:
            fout.write(contents)
def main():
        # my code here
        readfile("C:/Users/Johny The Overlord/Documents/Code/test.txt")
if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

> url in text1 https://twitter.com/xxx https://twitter.com/yyy
>   https://twitter.com/zzz
>
> in text2 should have
>
> https://twitter.com/xxx
>   target="_blank">@xxx
>
> https://twitter.com/yyy
>   target="_blank">@yyy
>
> https://twitter.com/zzz
>   target="_blank">@zzz

but it only write last url.
how do I fix?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is just because of writing mode. Try using "a" or"a+" to amend have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/23051095/3759158

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the previous one, try to write it (i mean in write function) in separate lines.

Add `fout.write("\n")` to your write functions after `fout.write(contents)`