# Python Script doesn´t lowercase the text from the file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying since the last 3 days make a script where user can puts his file and the script edit the text for put in lowercase all the words. I think that code is correct, I tried other forms for program this script but is not working me (including this code).

The problem is that when you run the python script and you put the file that you want to edit never edits the text that is infile the document. (if someone is asking self where is the file .txt, is in the same folder like the script.)

Here the code:

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
 
with open(fname, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        l=line.title()
        print(l)
```

Is really simple but is not working... And I don´t know why. Also I tried to put the absolute rute but is not working... :/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean that the file itself should be modified?

Comment: This prints line for line on the console. It does not modify the file content, for that you would need to store it into a new file and delete the old file/rename the lowercase copy.

Comment: str.title() wont lowercase all words. str.lower() would.

Comment: The `fileinput` module conveniently offers an option to modify your input file in-place.

Comment: A better design would let the user pass in the file(s) to modify as command-line arguments. Requiring interactive I/O makes your script hard to use as a component in a larger script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `str.lower()`:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as fileObj:
   for line in fileObj:
       line = line.lower()
```

one-liner:

```
file = open(filename, 'rt').read().lower()
```

Note (on the `rt` mode):

[on linux, there's no difference between text mode and binary mode, however, in windows, they converts `\n` to `\r\n` when text mode.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23051062/open-files-in-rt-and-wt-modes)

Answer (score 0):

Instead read the file and write the title content again to the file:

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
f = open(fname)
s = f.read().strip().title()
f.close()
f = open(fname,"w")
f.write(s)
f.close()
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks a lot I tried this and is working me!! Now I understand where is the problem! =) Thanks a lot! <3