# What is the difference between `tr` and `r` mode in Python?

Tags: python

I read that `tr` mode is a default mode when you use `open()` function. But I noticed that if I will write in PyCharm this

```py
file = open("error.txt")
print(file)
```

than it will return `<_io.TextIOWrapper name='error.txt' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>`
I really can't understand what is the default mode: `r` or `tr`? And what is the difference?

Comment: I think this is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23051062/open-files-in-rt-and-wt-modes

Comment: [_"The default mode is `'r'` (open for reading text, **a synonym** of `'rt'`)."_](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)